What are the practical differences between amillennialism and historical premillennialism?
Among the different eschatological schemes in Christian theology, I perceive that amillennialism and historical premillennialism do not differ in what they believe will happen before the second coming of Christ. (Or at least, they do not have to. I know that there exist some disagreements about futurist vs. preterist understandings of Matt. 24 or about the gathering of Israel in Rom. 11, but it does not seem to be the case that the interpretations of these passages separate premillennialist from amillennialist in general.) Postmillennialism and dispensational premillennialism on the other hand differ from one another and the aforementioned views in that they assert a different timeline of pre-Second Coming events, with postmillennialism looking forward to a millennium of the triumphant church and dispensationalism looking forward to a pre-tribulational rapture (and a very different understanding of that tribulation than would be found in other views).
I am wondering what difference does the distinction between historical premillennialism and amillennialism make, practically speaking? Does it have any effect on how Christians will conduct themselves in the present age? I can see that, if we look forward to different events prior to Christ's return, this may affect the way we live our lives now, in order that we might be prepared to face those circumstances. However, I do not see how the difference between historical premillennialists and amillennialists who agree on those issues would lead to any different practice of the faith in the present time.

Excellent Question It is noble to seek unity and harmony as much as possible since this usually affects conduct and practices as well. And the "watching world" (as Francis Schaeffer used to write) needs to see a united front of
"love among the brethren."
Main DifferenceThe main difference between Historic Premillennialists and the Amillennialists is their interpretation of the 1,000 year period mentioned in the symbolic book of Revelation. Whereas some of the ancient Church theologians saw a literal, physical era in the nebulous future, the others interpreted John's millennial as symbolic of the present era of the Kingdom. The historian Eusebius mentioned the tension between the two views.  And he considered both advocates as "orthodox believers." Neither were cultists---and there had arisen so many cults by then!
The Amillennialists put much weight on the legitimate interpretation of the genre of the apocalyptic literature. There were several Apocalypses written during the turn of the BC/AD calendar. The Jews had engaged in this type of writing just when Christianity was beginning its illustrious origin. And John the Revelator took up this style to illustrate the dynamic tension between the Church and the world---both paganism and philosophy. The persecuted Christians were "going through hell" while presenting the Way to heaven!  John showed the ultimate victory of goodness over evil, truth over error, love over hate.
The apocalyptic genre, according to Amillennialists, is not to be interpreted as prophecy nor even prophetic history. Rather, this type of literature is a tract of encouragement written using many symbols. (Compare the Jewish apocalypses as well, which if taken literally, would lead to absurdities.) The 1000 year period, therefore, is symbolic of the Church era (Kingdom of God).
This recognition of, and emphasis on, the present struggles between the Kingdoms of Light and Darkness, leads the Amillennialist to fend diligently for the Faith in the Present time.  He does not hope for a future era of a manifest Kingdom, but is focused on working for the Kingdom's establishment throughout the Earth now. That is, a spiritual kingdom.

The Kingdom of God is righteousness, peace, and joy in the Holy Ghost. (Romans 10)

Historic Premillennialists Those who are Premillennialists do indeed put emphasis on working for the Present Kingdom in this Church Age. And they could easily work hand-in-hand with Amillennialists in this endeavor. The promises of God are yea and amen in Christ, right now. What Christ intended to set up and establish in His Church is available right now: a ministry anointed by the Holy Spirit bringing life and healing to the nations. Whatever the millennium is to be (physical to the premillennialist), it is still a time focused on Jesus and the Church, not a Jewish kingdom with David as an alleged king. [Some teach a future revival among the Jews...but it is a spiritual revival returning to Christ as Messiah, Lord of the Church without any difference between Jew and Gentile, not a physical return to some real estate.]
End Time Both the Pre- and A- put a lot less stress on alleged "End time signs" and "end-time events" of a pyro-technological, apocalyptic nature! Most even deny any signs, since this was the teaching of Jesus with repeated illustrations.

Be ready, for you know not the day nor hour when the Son of Man returns!

The Second Coming of Christ is the blessed hope both wait for. In the mean time both are busy evangelistically, and do not teach any "escape event" (rapture) that treats the Church as a "plan B" that needs to get out of the way so a Jewish people can take over the world (with a lot of fighting going on). God's Kingdom is not established by military means. It is a spiritual Kingdom with spiritual warfare; since we fight against principalities and powers of darkness.
Both groups are allies in this evangelistic outreach to the world. Emphasis is not on a fear of end-time scenarios but a faith in the transforming power of the Gospel to change warriors into saints.
Resources Some resource books include: What, Where, and When is the Millennium? (R. Bradley Jones), Interpreting Prophecy (Philip E. Hughes), The Cosmic Drama (Herschel H. Hobbs), Inspired Principles of Prophetic Interpretation (John Wilmot), A Case for Amillennialism (Kim Riddlebarger), Coming Again, But When? (Jerry Newcombe).

Well said, but I'm not sure it really answers my question - would you say the difference between amillennialism and historical premillennialism is just one of hermeneutics?

@ Dark Malthrop - Yes, hermeneutics plays a great part: Spiritual kingdom until the very End vs. Spiritual kingdom morphing into a literal (physical) kingdom in the End.  [Amill vs Premill] But not as much emphasis is placed on the Jews as a distinct people in Amill as in Premill.  In amill,  the fulness of the Gentiles, and the remnant of Jews, are evangelistically co-occurring. --- While both look forward to a triumphant Church, the premill look forward to a literal 1,000 year period later, whereas the Amill consider the 1,000 to be symbolic of the era between Christ's 1st and 2nd comings.

Amillennialists do not believe that all true believers will be 'raptured' up into heaven before a period of terrible tribulation starts on the earth. (Often claimed by pre-millennialists or, pre-tribulationists, to be a literal 7 years of awful conditions on earth.) They believe that all Christians alive at the start of what Revelation describes as the finale of various plagues already poured out on Earth, from heaven, will have to go through that dreadful time, up until Christ suddenly comes to usher in the Day of Judgment and Resurrection.
Amillennialists do not believe that Christ's return will usher in his literally sitting on a throne in a new Jerusalem on earth, ruling for 1,000 years. They do not expect this world to come to acceptance of Christ and the gospel, with 'the Church on Earth' having a golden era of influence and acceptance. They believe Christ's unexpected return will include the fiery destruction of this Earth and the heavens, with a new heavens and a new Earth, in which righteousness will dwell, formed at God's command.
They do not believe various other things that pre-millennialists believe, but I'm sticking only to points that should show practical differences between the two groups. It is not semantic differences, or hermeneutical or interpretative differences that are asked for, but practical differences: how that should work out in practice, not in theory.
Already, it should be seen that those differing viewpoints are opposing viewpoints, not similar ones that don't make any substantial difference, as many premillennialists seem to think. People who are bracing themselves for a dreadful time of persecution think and live differently to those who cheerfully claim that they will be snatched up and away before it explodes on the world scene.
Amillennialists who have studied the warnings written in the book of Revelation about the last set of 7 plagues, are looking out (already) for something that cannot be seen with literal eyes. In the quote below, the author has shown how - despite various plagues poured out by God's angels - men did not repent, but cursed God more and more. Then comes this quote from scripture, to show by allegory what believers in the prophecy of Revelation need to look out for, but not with literal vision:

'And I saw three unclean spirits like frogs come out of the mouth of
the dragon, and out of the mouth of the beast, and out of the mouth of
the false prophet. For they are the spirits of devils, working
miracles, which go forth unto the kings of the earth and of the whole
world to gather them to the battle of the great day of God Almighty' -
a parenthesis follows, but I continue the direct narrative - 'and he
gathered them together into a place called in the Hebrew tongue
Armageddon', Rev. 16:12-14 and v. 16.
...As with the sounding of the sixth trumpet, ch. 9:13-21, so with the
revelation at the last day consequent upon the outpouring of the sixth
vial... Absolutely nothing is literal. Literally everything is
allegorical. If this cannot be grasped, nothing will be grasped, and
the reader will stumble about on the dark mountains, or grope for
the wall like the blind." The Revelation of Jesus Christ, John
Metcalfe, pp. 442-3, 1998, [emphasis mine]
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Therein lies a massive, practical difference between the two groups. One is looking ahead to the last day to identify that which cannot be seen literally; the other literally expects to see world events working out according to their premillennial interpretations and expectations, for example, with a literal, visible mark of the beast. If the latter are, indeed, wrong, they will be caught unawares when the foretold events happen. This is because of...
The next massive, practical difference:  Revelation warns of a satanic deception that will be foisted upon an unsuspecting world through those symbolic 'unclean spirits' that come out of the mouths of the symbolic 'dragon', and 'beast, and 'false prophet'. (This is the first time in Revelation that the second beast is called the false prophet, because a lying spirit fills such a deceiver.)

"The kings of the east were drawn by the three unclean spirits. Could
these be seen, they would appear like frogs, from which the kings
would shrink, utterly repelled. But they cannot be seen. No, nor even
felt. Yet their imperceptible drawing, in which these spirits disguise
their very existence, so that the kings are oblivious of them,
nevertheless moves the kings with irresistible pressure. [The Greek
word, piezo means pressure/squeeze (SG4085), credit for that point
to Dieter.]
...the fulfilment appears in a revelation of coming world unity, of
world dominion, when with one accord every nation, kindred, tongue,
and people, will turn with exasperated fury against the surviving
remnant according to the election of grace. In the prophetic figure,
the remaining saints - unlike the whole earth and the entire world - refuse to worship the beast, or his image, or to receive his mark either in forehead or hand, or yield to the number of his
name." (Ibid. p. 444 [emphasis mine])

Now if premillennialists expect to have been raptured away before this happens, but remain, are not they likely to be deceived and lured into the great deception the dragon has enacted to cause the world to worship him (though they don't realise it's him they are serving)?
A final difference, based on views of the Church, is that amillennialists do not have the outlook that the Church will be triumphant, on Earth, for 1,000 years. They expect satanic efforts to crush the Church entirely to culminate shortly before Jesus returns. It will only be after the first creation has been consumed in a plasma of divine heat, that the new heavens and the new Earth, in which righteousness will dwell (2 Peter 3:10-13 & Rev. 21:1) shall replace the old order. That difference does cause a practical difference in what gospel message is preached by the differing groups. Those with the earthly hope (the premillennialists) love to dwell on earthly, physical matters. I used to belong to one such group and have written a book about that sort of thing. That group certainly did not have heaven in mind, for it was not their hope. Consequently, their gospel message was all about what they hoped to enjoy on Earth during the millennium. That's how they lured people in. But not all premillennialists are like that, I hasten to add. Yet, to varying degrees, their millennial hopes distort their gospel message. That requires a different book. Maybe it's already been written (but not by me!)
Conclusion: Those 3 differences combine in a chilling way, for wrong expectations lead to two terrible errors: (1) being deceived by the invisible dragon pulling the strings of those in politics and religion who don't have spiritual 'vision' of what he's doing. (2) That will lead to a distorted gospel even by some who believe in Jesus, so that when the final deception unfolds, it will be too late for all who have been deceived. That invisible deception is already being worked out. The culmination will lead to disaster for all who have not 'seen' the urgency of today. They will continue eating, drinking, marrying etc. as in Noah's day, and will take no note, for they suppose they are going to be just fine. That warning applies to all professing Christians, not just those in this or that 'camp'.

I don't think this answers my question, as it seems to be explaining the difference between dispensational premillennialism and amillennialism.

@DarkMalthorp The practical difference of both groups having different gospel messages seems to be the elephant in the room, I suggest. Any distortion to the biblical gospel results in a warped, false, deceptive message that will not lead to the saving of souls. The need is surely to identify which of the different gospel messages is not the biblical one?

Yes, I agree with what you wrote, but I was not asking about dispensationalism but rather the historical premillnnialism, which doesn't believe in a pre-trib rapture or any of the other excesses of dispensationalism. I'm wondering if, in absence of disagreement about the pre-parousia events, what is the practical consequences of taking a premil or amil view of the millennium?

@DarkMalthorpe  I was building on my recent answer to your related Q, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/101838/what-is-the-cause-of-the-re-emergence-of-premillennialism Due to dispensationalism now having a strong grip on many premillennialists today, we now have a jumble of ideas, but the notion of a literal 1,000 year rule on Earth remains common to both groups. This was also a prime view in historic premillennialism. I tried to show the outworking of that, as wrong doctrine here will distort the gospel, which is a fundamentally practical difference. Sorry if I failed.

I see. Perhaps my perspective is too compartmentalized. I am trying to understand how the millennium itself affects praxis, without the whole system of dispensationalism and its weirdness.

@DarkMalthorp The way the millennium affects accepted practice/custom would be hard to ascertain except in the realms of belief and attitudes. That is why I stuck to how it affects gospel belief/teaching. That seems to me to be the best way to discover practical differences between the two groups. But, then, my way of thinking is a bit odd!
